# Express $a_n$ and $b_n$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Let $$a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n + b_n}2,\quad b_{n+1} = \frac{a_{n+1} + b_n}2.$$

Express $a_n$ and $b_n$ in terms of $a_1$, $b_1$ and $n$

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Honestly, I do not know how to express it in English properly as I have studied this topic in Russian. I've got an answer by considering $a_2$, $a_3$, etc in terms of $a_1$ and $b_1$ (and then did the same thing with $b_2$, $b_3$, etc). I noticed some dependencies and then solved a number of recurrence relations. I only want to make sure whether my answers are right or not and discover new solutions

Comment: thx, it is exactly what I needed :)

Comment: @Ilnas Beridze:$\;$Correcting my earlier comment (now deleted), we can manipulate the given bivariate recurrences to get
$$
a_n=\frac{5}{4}a_{n-1}-\frac{1}{4}a_{n-2}\\
b_n=\frac{5}{4}b_{n-1}-\frac{1}{4}b_{n-2}
$$
for all $n\ge 3$.
$$$$
Using standard techniques for solving univariate linear recurrences with constant coefficients, we get
$$
a_n
=
\frac{a_1+2b_1}{3}
+
\frac{8(a_1-b_1)}{3}
{\,\cdot\,}
\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n
\\
b_n
=
\frac{a_1+2b_1}{3}
+
\frac{4(b_1-a_1)}{3}
{\,\cdot\,}
\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\begin{pmatrix}a_{n+1}\\ b_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac12&\frac12\\ \frac14&\frac34\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_{n}\\ b_{n}\end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: +1: Is this valid even if the matrix is not diagonalizable?

Comment: Is it possible to solve the problem without a matrix?

Comment: @IlnasBeridze Yea, just treat it as a linear transformation. Treating it as a matrix definitely seems like the better approach, though.